# AppCenter build fails with no such module

Tags: ios, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

My automatic iOS build on AppCenter fails with the following error (snippet):

```
ViewController.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'MBCircularProgressBar'
import MBCircularProgressBar
       ^
```

But I don't know what the problem might be. I'm using CocoaPods to import that framework.

My `Podfile` looks like this (removed all other pods):

```
target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'MBCircularProgressBar'
end
```

And I have a Post Clone script `appcenter-post-clone.sh` which is recognized in AppCenter that contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pod repo update
pod install
```

**EDIT:** After moving the offending file down in the list of files to compile, I get the same error for another CocoaPod. So it seems to me that no CocoaPods are being found

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you check you are building your projects workspace? You'll need to build the workspace in orde to get Cocoapods to work, not the Xcode project.

Comment: Oh god  Thanks!

Comment: And how to do it?

Comment: @AlexeiMikhailov : In Appcenter, you can open the build configuration for a git branch. The Project/Workspace field Should be set to the “.xcworkspace” file instead of “.xcodeproj”

Comment: Thank you very much! I was facing the same problem.

Comment: Sorry could not find any Project/Workspace field in the build configuration... where is it?

Comment: @chenop,

What kind of app are you trying to build? Is it native iOS (swift)? Or React-Native?

Comment: @JeroenCrevits it react-native - I later understood its the first "Project" field - didnt help for me but I solved it by going back to an older commit